# How to get a struct value from a Trait Object?

Tags: rust

I'm experimenting with Traits in Rust and trying to extract a value from a struct that is passed through a Trait Object. Here's the code I'm working with:

```rust
pub trait Adder {
    fn add(&mut self, example: &dyn Adder);
}

pub struct X {
    pub val: usize,
}

pub struct Y {
    pub val: usize,
}

impl Adder for X {
    fn add(&mut self, example: &dyn Adder) {
        // I want to get example.val here, whether it's X or Y
        // The operation I want to do is self.val += example.val;
    }
}

impl Adder for Y {
    fn add(&mut self, example: &dyn Adder) {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = X { val: 1 };
    let y = Y { val: 1 };
    x.add(&y);
}
```

I found an alternative online using `std::any::Any`, but changing my `Adder Trait` to use it like this:

```rust
pub trait Adder {
    fn add(&mut self, example: &dyn Any);
}
```

works, but it's not what I want because now anything can be passed to `example`, even a struct with a different Trait implementation:

```rust
...
struct Z;
pub trait ZTrait {}

fn main() {
    let mut x = X { val: 1 };
    let y = Y { val: 1 };

    let z = Z;
    x.add(&z);
}
```

Is there an alternative way to extract the value from the Trait Object?

Comment: The duplicate applies, however note that this is generally an antipattern, even more than in other languages.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might not want or need the actual struct (or downcasting, or any other means of recovering a concrete type.) Instead, can you decompose this into multiple traits that encompass what you need? For instance, a `ValueHolder` trait that provides `val`; `Adder` can then extend `ValueHolder`, and `X`'s implementation of `Adder` can rely on the `getVal` functionality from `ValueHolder`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman could you provide a reference on why this is a antipattern? I'd like to learn more about it to avoid using it in my code.

Comment: @EdwardPeters thank you for the clarity, i've tried it and it works!
`pub trait ValueHolder { fn getVal(&self) -> usize;}` and `pub trait Adder:ValueHolder`

Comment: Hmm... I don't know a specific reference, but (a) it is only available with `'static` types, (b) Rust usually favors static polymorphism (generics) over dynamic polymorphism (`dyn Trait`), and downcasting works with the latter. There is usually a more idiomatic way to do what you want with static polymorphism. And of course, it is very brittle, but this is true in any language.